# Predicting new data using glm and cv.glmnet in R (including interactions and categorical variables )

Tags: r, regression, prediction, glm

I'd like to model a regression formula including interactions ad categorical variables. I am interested to use glm and glmnet::cv.glmnet. I am ok with the functions which fit the model but am not quite sure that I am using the trained models to forecast out sample data correctly. Here is an example.

```
Formula <- "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + as.factor(Species):Petal.Width + Sepal.Width:Petal.Length +  as.factor(Species) +  bs(Petal.Width, df = 2, degree = 2)"

data("iris")
Inx <- sample( 1: nrow(iris), nrow(iris),  replace = F)

iris$Species <- as.factor(iris$Species)

train_data <- iris[Inx[1:100], ]
test_data <- iris[Inx[101:nrow(iris) ],]

#---- glm -----------------
ModelMatrix <- predict(caret::dummyVars(Formula, train_data, fullRank = T, sep = ""), train_data)
glmfit <- glm(formula = as.formula(Formula) , data = train_data)

prd_glm <- predict(glmfit, newx = ModelMatrix, type = "response")

#------- glm cross validation --------------
cvglm <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = ModelMatrix,
                           y = train_data$Sepal.Length,
                           nfolds = 4, keep = TRUE, alpha = 1, parallel = F, type.measure = 'mse')

ModelMatrix_test <- predict(caret::dummyVars(Formula, test_data, fullRank = T, sep = ""), test_data)
prd_cvglm <- predict(cvglm, newx = ModelMatrix_test,  s = "lambda.1se", type ='response')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either use a modelmatrix, or a formula, but not both, because once you provide a formula, any glm will internally generates model matrix. And you factor only once. So in your case, let's say directly fit the model matrx:

```
library(splines)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)

data(iris)
Inx <- sample(nrow(iris),100)
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)

train_data <- iris[Inx, ]
test_data <- iris[-Inx,]

Formula <- "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Species:Petal.Width + Sepal.Width:Petal.Length +  Species +  bs(Petal.Width, df = 2, degree = 2)"

glmfit <- glm(as.formula(Formula),data=train_data)
```

You can see this is the same as fitting with a formula:

```
ModelMatrix <- predict(caret::dummyVars(Formula, train_data, fullRank = T, sep = ""), train_data)
y = train_data[,"Sepal.Length"]
fit_dummy = glm(y ~ ModelMatrix)
table(fitted(glmfit) == fitted(fit_dummy))
TRUE 
 100
```

And we predict on the test data:

```
prd_glm <- predict(glmfit, newdata = test_data, type = "response")
```

Then for glmnet:

```
cvglm <- cv.glmnet(x = ModelMatrix,y = train_data$Sepal.Length,nfolds = 4, 
    keep = TRUE, alpha = 1, parallel = F, type.measure = 'mse')

ModelMatrix_test <- predict(caret::dummyVars(Formula, test_data, fullRank = T, sep = ""), test_data)
prd_cvglm <- predict(cvglm, newx = ModelMatrix_test,  s = "lambda.1se", type ='response')
```

You can see how they differ:

```
plot(prd_glm,prd_cvglm)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nile, if it is a different question, please post it as a separate question. Otherwise your question and my answer will not match and be totally confusing.

Comment: please respect that SO is also meant as a repository of useful questions and answers meant for the whole community. In the future, if someone else has the same issue as the answer above, my answer together with your question will help

Comment: By editing and changing it to different needs, this destroys the whole purpose of SO and is not very constructive or useful for everyone. Please adhere to this @Nile